# Is there a way to duplicate a row for each related record in filamentphp's many-to-many relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

i have a many to many relationship between model A and model B , and how filament works, if i do the following:

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('modelB.name'),
```

i will get all the names of the relationship separated by a comma.

what i am looking to achieve is the following | Model A record | Model B name (1st record)|

|model A record | Model B name (2nd record)|

and so on, so in short i want to duplicate the row for each of the model B records that are linked to model A.

i couldn't find in docs that i can build my custom table structure, only columns, so is the above possible to do, or should i ask for it to be implemented as a feature.

Thank you

i tried custom column type but wouldn't work unless i do all the extra pivot data within that column too